# Must supply cloud_name in Cloudinary heroku deploy

Tags: node.js, cloudinary, dotenv

I've declared the `CLOUD_NAME, CLOUD_KEY, CLOUD_SECRET` in the `.env` file and when I try to do `git push heroku master` it shows errors as:

```
2022-07-14T13:21:28.836730+00:00 app[web.1]: Must supply cloud_name
2022-07-14T13:21:28.836731+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
2022-07-14T13:21:28.976355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-14T13:21:29.107460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-14T13:21:43.021994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=react-bank-mysql.herokuapp.com request_id=6d906e55-283a-4669-bc37-b66380d65ba0 fwd="49.36.100.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-14T13:21:43.334479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=react-bank-mysql.herokuapp.com request_id=b4c0fd71-4de1-4a95-b7e9-55b86f4c697c fwd="49.36.100.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-14T13:22:36.489119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=react-bank-mysql.herokuapp.com request_id=177b60b5-6e3d-4b33-a329-b2b87448235a fwd="49.36.100.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-14T13:22:36.778798+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=react-bank-mysql.herokuapp.com request_id=5bf1946e-68c4-4d77-85aa-54ea4ac0c873 fwd="49.36.100.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I tried using [this](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/blob/master/samples/basic/basic.js) by commenting the code as shown and also adding my `CLOUDINARY_URL` but that didn't worked too

```
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
require("dotenv").config();

//Connect to Cloudinary && Folder
// cloudinary.config({
//   cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
//   api_key: process.env.CLOUD_KEY,
//   api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_SECRET,
//   secure: true,
// });
```

Anyone with solution would be helpful

Comment: Could you log the values of `process.env.CLOUD_NAME` for example in your configuration? The error you're seeing is most likely because indeed those env variables do not contain any values. Did you add the variables in your Heroku Config too?

Comment: @Aleksandar Yes it is logging my cloud_name and as of the heroku config, I don't have much idea for that, I tried adding add-ons for Cloudinary but its asking for credit card

Comment: Could you try to add the Env variables in the Dashboard (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the environment variables in Heroku using Heroku's [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars). The `.env` file is used for your local development and should not be checked into your git repo. When deploying on Heroku, you use config vars.

For example:

```
heroku config:set CLOUD_NAME=my-cloud-name
```

You can also set these in the Heroku Dashboard if you prefer that to the CLI.

See the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars) for more info.

Comment: Yeah I set them all and running successfully